# Mulitple column insert

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, file-upload

I have multiple custom file inputs in my module , id like to save all this inputs in my database table ("Custom table , not the Joomla tables") , below is my code , which saves only 1 input , there are 4 inputs :

**helper.php**

```
class moduploaddocumentsHelper
{
    /**
     * Retrieves the hello message
     *
     * @param   array  $params An object containing the module parameters
     *
     * @access public
     */
    public static function getdata()
    {
       //Retrieve file details from uploaded file, sent from upload form
        $file = JRequest::getVar('highestacademic', null, 'files', 'array');

        //Import filesystem libraries. Perhaps not necessary, but does not hurt
        jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');

        //Clean up filename to get rid of strange characters like spaces etc
        $filename =  uniqid().JFile::makeSafe($file['name']);
        //Set up the source and destination of the file
        $src = $file['tmp_name'];
        $dest = JPATH_BASE . DS . "media" . DS ."documents" . DS . $filename;


        // $name=$post['highestacademic']['name'] ;
        //First check if the file has the right extension, we need jpg only
        if ( strtolower(JFile::getExt($filename) ) == 'jpg' || strtolower(JFile::getExt($filename) ) == 'png') {
           if ( JFile::upload($src, $dest) ) {
             $user = JFactory::getUser();
             $useid = $user->id ;
             // Obtain a database connection
            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            // Create a new query object.
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);
            // Insert columns.
            $columns = array('user_id', 'document_name');

            // Insert values.
            $values = array($useid, $db->quote($filename) );
            // Retrieve the shout
            $query
                    ->insert($db->quoteName('#__documents'))
                    ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
                    ->values(implode(',', $values));
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $db->execute();
            JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage(JText::_('DOCUMENT SUCCESFULLY UPLOADED'), 'Message');

           } else {
             echo "error !"; //Redirect and throw an error message
           }
        } else {
           echo "Wrong extension !"; //Redirect and notify user file is not right extension
        }
         return $dest ;

    }
 }
```

**/tmpl/default.php**

```
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="highestacademic">Attachment of Highest Academic Qualifications</label>
        <input name="highestacademic" type="file" id="highestacademic">
        <p class="help-block">Degree, Diploma, Pre-University, GCE O-Levels, etc.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="language">Attachment of Language Qualifications</label>
        <input name="language" type="file" id="language">
        <p class="help-block">TOEFL, IELTS , etc.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="passport">Attachment of Passport Copy</label>
        <input name="passport" type="file" id="passport">
        <p class="help-block">ID or Passport copies both sides.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="supporting">Other Supporting Documents</label>
        <input name="supporting" type="file" id="supporting">
        <p class="help-block">Other supporting documents ie photos ,etc .</p>
      </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved this by using `$jinput->files->get()` as in below :

Note the `doc[1]`  which puts all upload files in an array in the `Jinput` object here `$files = $jinput->files->get('docs');`

**helper.php**

```
class moddocumentsHelper
{
    /**
     * Retrieves the hello message
     *
     * @param   array  $params An object containing the module parameters
     *
     * @access public
     */
    public static function getdata()
    {
        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
       //Retrieve file details from uploaded file, sent from upload form
        //$file = JRequest::getVar('highestacademic', null, 'files', 'array');
         $files = $jinput->files->get('docs');
        //Import filesystem libraries. Perhaps not necessary, but does not hurt
         jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
        foreach($files as $key => $file ){
          if($file['name'] !== " "){
             // //Clean up filename to get rid of strange characters like spaces etc
               $filename =  uniqid().$file['name'];
              // //Set up the source and destination of the file
                $src = $file['tmp_name'];
                $dest = JPATH_BASE . DS . "media" . DS ."documents" . DS . $filename;



              // //First check if the file has the right extension, we need jpg only
               if ( strtolower(JFile::getExt($filename) ) == 'jpg' || strtolower(JFile::getExt($filename) ) == 'png' || strtolower(JFile::getExt($filename) ) == 'pdf' || strtolower(JFile::getExt($filename) ) == 'doc') {
                   if ( JFile::upload($src, $dest) ) {
                    $user = JFactory::getUser();
                    $useid = $user->id ;
              //     // Obtain a database connection
                    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
              //     // Create a new query object.
                    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
              //     // Insert columns.
                   $columns = array('user_id', 'document_name' ,'type');

              //     // Insert values.
                   $values = array($useid, $db->quote($filename) , $db->quote($key));
              //     // Retrieve the shout
                   $query
                           ->insert($db->quoteName('#__documents'))
                           ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
                           ->values(implode(',', $values));
                   $db->setQuery($query);
                   $db->execute();

              //     // Redirect to a page of your choice
              //     // header("Location: http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/administrator");
                 } else {
                  echo "error !"; //Redirect and throw an error message
                 }
               } else {
                 echo "Wrong extension !"; //Redirect and notify user file is not right extension
              }
          }

        }


         return $files ;

    }



}
```

**tmpl/default.php**

```
 <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="highestacademic">Attachment of Highest Academic Qualifications</label>
        <input name="docs[1]" type="file" id="highestacademic">
        <p class="help-block">Degree, Diploma, Pre-University, GCE O-Levels, etc.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="language">Attachment of Language Qualifications</label>
        <input name="docs[2]" type="file" id="language">
        <p class="help-block">TOEFL, IELTS , etc.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="passport">Attachment of Passport Copy</label>
        <input name="docs[3]" type="file" id="passport">
        <p class="help-block">ID or Passport copies both sides.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="supporting">Other Supporting Documents</label>
        <input name="docs[4]" type="file" id="supporting">
        <p class="help-block">Other supporting documents ie photos ,etc .</p>
      </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: More sensible to not repeat method/function calls on the same string. `if ( strtolower(JFile::getExt($filename) ) == 'jpg' || strtolower(JFile::getExt($filename) ) == 'png' || strtolower(JFile::getExt($filename) ) == 'pdf' || strtolower(JFile::getExt($filename) ) == 'doc') {
             ` becomes `if (in_array(strtolower(JFile::getExt($filename)), ['jpg', 'png', 'pdf', 'doc'])) {`

Comment: Since you have resolved your own question, please award the green tick to your answer.